# How to grep new line character present in a column in text file

Tags: linux, unix

I have one text file with data separated by pipe delimiter.I have one column named address having new line character in the address value.
I have to remove new line from the file. Is there any way to  grep the new line character from the address field?

Comment: `I have to remove new line from the file. Is there any way to grep the new line` but if you want to remove it, why `grep`?

Answer (score 0):

This is very fragile, and you may want to make it robust, but you could try something like:

```
$ cat input
a|b|c|d|e|f|g
1|2|3
a|4|5|6|7
$ awk 'NF<7{getline a; $0 = $0 a}1' FS=\| input
a|b|c|d|e|f|g
1|2|3a|4|5|6|7
```

If you're worried about multiple fields containing the record separator, or runs of newlines, you might try:

```
awk '{while( split($0, a, "\|") < 7 ){if(getline b) $0 = $0 b; else exit;}}1' FS=\| input
```

(In each, I've arbitrarily chosen 7 as the number of expected columns, but that's easy to parameterize.)

Comment: One way in which this is fragile is if a string field contains a pipe symbol.  There are several conventions for noting that the pipe is part of the string and not a field separator.  CSV encloses the whole field in quotes.  Informix UNLOAD format prefixes the pipe with a backslash.  In other contexts, the troublesome character is repeated (SQL repeats a single quote inside a single-quoted string, for example).  Without more information, there's not a lot more you can do, though.